# In EntityFramework how do you reload entities in a Many to Many relationship?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-3.5, many-to-many, objectcontext

First off I'm using .Net 3.5 SP1.  I have a few entities related as follows.
An `Engineer` has many `Appointments`
An `Appointment` has many `Engineers`
A `Timeslot` has many `Appointments`
I'm providing functionality in my data access layer to undo/discard changes made to entities.  I'm doing this by calling...

```
ObjectContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, Entity entity);
```

This works fine for the entity itself and any 1 to Many relationships like the `Timeslot` but doesn't revert any changes to the Many to Many relationships.

How woulld I go around reverting changes to Many to Many relationships preferably in a Generic manor as currently my `DiscardChanges()` function is in a base class?

Comment: Have you tried the overload of the Refresh which takes a collection instead of a single entity?

Comment: That would undo changes to a collection of Entity objects, but what I need to do is restore the original collection of related entities in my many to many relationship. For some reason Refresh doesn't do this.

Comment: I also have the same issue.
For my opinon it's a shame that Microsoft didn't include the magic Refresh(rm RefreshMode) method in the ObjectContext just like SaveChanges(), should be something opposite, like DiscardChanges for ALL the tracked objects.
If you have any news in your research please buzz in, meanwhile you might also wanna take a look at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/c12bd8c8-231f-4dcc-a665-b048f7debbd7/

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit convoluted, but this has worked for me to refresh M2M relations:

```
myengineer.Appointments.Clear();
context.AcceptAllChanges();
myengineer.Appointments.Load();
```

Comment: M2M? O.o as in male to male relationship? (O.o)